# How to change name of keys of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays one of them  contain a new key name

```
$assoc = ['name', 'lastname', 'pesel'];
```

and second look this

```
$inputs = ['John', 'Don', '987987', 'Mike', 'Evans', '89779' ];
```

Array `$assoc` is the new key name, and I would like to change `[0]`,`[1]` to `['name']` etc

```
array(2) {
  ['person'] =>
  array(3) {
    ['name'] => string(4) "John"
    ['lastname'] => string(3) "Don"
    ['pesel'] => string(6) "987987"
  }
  ['person'] =>
  array(3) {
    ['name'] => string(4) "Mike"
    ['lastname'] => string(5) "Evans"
    ['pesel'] => string(5) "89779"
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Use `array_chunk` on your value list, then bind keys to each chunk using `array_combine`.

Comment: You can't have multiple elements in one array that have the same key. The latter will overwrite the former. So `array( 'person' => ..., 'person' => ... )` will not be an array with two elements.

Comment: yes you have right :) i'm so stupid

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
$assoc=Array("name", "lastname", "pesel");
$inputs=Array('John', 'Don', '987987', 'Mike', 'Evans', '89779' );

$resultant_array=Array();
for($i=0; $i<count($inputs); $i+=count($assoc)){
//echo $i."\n\n";
 for($j=0; $j<count($assoc); $j++){

    $b2g[$assoc[$j]]=$inputs[$i+$j];
 }
 $resultant_array[]=$b2g;
}   

print_r($resultant_array);
```

It is a more lengthy and general purpose use.. I actually have used much recurssions..

Comment: Weird that you preferred this answer to mine... I assume you like things cluttery.

Comment: No. I like exploring with code rather looking for it on Google.. both takes same time

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty simple:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach(array_chunk($inputs, 3) as $person) {
   $new_array[] = array_combine($assoc, $person);
}
```